# Multiple listeners with telegraf/filters

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegraf

I'm using telegraf in node js.

I have multiple on functions with `import { message} from 'telegraf/filters'`.

```
bot.on(message('text'), ...)
...
bot.on(message('photo'), ...)
```

Both listeners don't work at the same time. How do I make both work.